# Matplotlib:How to avoid '0' on the x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyomo, xticks

I'm using this code to plot a bar chart:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.subplot(211)
for i in instance.J:
    plt.bar(i, value(instance.P[i]))
plt.xlabel('Generators',fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Power (MW)',fontweight='bold')
plt.xlim(xmin=0)
plt.xticks(range(55),rotation=90,size=9)
plt.title('Power dispatch')
```

The result is shown below. How to avoid `0` on the x-axis?
Anyone can help me with this problem?

[image]

Comment: Just remove the `xlim` ?

Comment: It doesn't work, sir.

Comment: set `xmin=1` in `xlim` and change `xticks` to having `range(1, 55)`?

Comment: It has been fixed.As the answer from Quang Hoang: `plt.xticks(range(55), [a if a else '' for a in range(55)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try replacing the tick label at `0` with `''` like this:

```
plt.xticks(range(55), [a if a else '' for a in range(55)])
```

Comment: Due to `0` being falsy, `[a or '' for a in range(55)]` would also work, but it's certainly not as obvious :)